# Smart card reader development with .Net technologies

Tags: c#, smartcard, winscard

Does anyone know how to monitor the presence of smart card and read the UID value of the card?

Yes I tried lot of examples in web like

[A Smart Card Framework for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET)

[pcsc-sharp](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/PCSC/3.1.0.2/Release/.NETFramework,Version=v3.5/pcsc-sharp)

[Monitoring a Smartcard Reader](http://cgeers.com/2008/02/03/monitoring-a-smartcard-reader/)

But No idea how to do it. I can detect the presence of a card and can get the UID separately, but no idea how to combine them in my application:( .

Help me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figure it out. thought to share with anyone interested.

I used **winscard.dll** functions to access card data and communicate with PC.

Note that I used **Mifare 1K cards** as NFC tag and reader **ACR 122u**.

```
    private string getcardUID()//only for mifare 1k cards
    {
        string cardUID = "";
        byte[] receivedUID = new byte[256];
        Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST request = new Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST();
        request.dwProtocol = Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1;
        request.cbPciLength = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Card.SCARD_IO_REQUEST));
        byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; //get UID command      for Mifare cards
        int outBytes = receivedUID.Length;
        int status = Card.SCardTransmit(hCard, ref request, ref sendBytes[0], sendBytes.Length, ref request, ref receivedUID[0], ref outBytes);

        if (status != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            cardUID = "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            cardUID = BitConverter.ToString(receivedUID.Take(4).ToArray()).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
        }

        return cardUID;
    }
```

For anyone interested I've written step by step guide to achieve this in here.

[Simple NFC reading system for windows](https://iranthajayasekara.com/blog/nfc-card-reading-system-with-acr122u-reader.html)

Enjoy!!!

Comment: Can i Contact you to explain me how to call SmartCard with this dll? i have code Hexa of Commands APDU for My smartCards

Comment: URL not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

link above seems to be dead, I have made a reader writer also, it is in public repo if it is needed :
[CCID Reader Writer .net](https://dev.azure.com/guillaumehamel0676/_git/CCIDReaderWriter)